# Pervasive Database order by statement

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, pervasive

I have the following SQL statement:

```
select * 
from
    (select  
         id,
         left(id, 6) as Hauptnummer,
         convert(substring(id, 8), SQL_BIGINT) as Detailnummer
     from 
         Proben 
     where 
         id like '%-%'  
         and id like '2%' 
         and length(id) > 7) as a 
order by  
    Hauptnummer desc, Detailnummer
```

When I am running this statement I get the following error:

![ODBC-Engine Interface] expression error

The statement is executed correctly without the `ORDER BY` clause.

How can I write this `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: Please specify details of error-message.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to order by fields that are outside subquery.
Let's try same of this code (below is syntax of MS SQL):

```
/* declare and create temp (in-memory) table */
declare @proben table
(
    id nvarchar(24)
)

/* insert come test data to table */
insert @proben(id) values('2345-67890')
insert @proben(id) values('54654645-6257890')
insert @proben(id) values('2345-67890546541')
insert @proben(id) values('4355343542345-67890')

/* check of select of your script */
select *
from (
    select
        id,
        left(id, 6) as Hauptnummer,
        CAST(substring(id, 8, 0) AS BIGINT) as Detailnummer
    from
        @proben
    where
        id like '%-%'
        and id like '2%'
        and len(id) > 7
    order by
        Hauptnummer desc, Detailnummer
    ) as a
order by
    a.Hauptnummer desc, a.Detailnummer
```

Comment: thi salso doesnot work, I get the same error-message

Answer (score 0):

If the code used in SQL-Server(T-SQL) this can be achieved using the below:
Substring function accepts character conversion and hence code has been re-written in following manner. Syntax for substring function:
`SUBSTRING(string, start, length)`

for example:

```
select * 
from
    (select  
        id,
        left(id, 6) as Hauptnummer, 
        substring(convert (varchar(20), id ), 1, 2) as Detailnummer 
     from 
        Proben 
     where 
        id like '%-%'  
        and id like '2%'  
        and len(id) > 7) as a  /* SQL server it is len instead length */
order by  
    Hauptnummer desc, Detailnummer
```

Comment: i am using Perasive database